# How to toggle all breakpoints in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I am looking for a way to assign a keyboard shortcut that would toggle all breakpoints in VS Code.

The same key should either disable them all or enable them all back, i.e. it is not about only disabling or only enabling them via two different shortcuts.

I cannot find any action responsible for that. There are only `disableAllBreakpoints`, `enableAllBreakpoints`, `removeAllBreakpoints` and `reapplyBreakpointsAction`.

The last one sounds somewhat promising but I am not sure if this is the one that I am looking for? It does not toggle them so perhaps this is not it?

Essentially, I am looking for a `toggleAllBreakpoints` but I am not sure if it exists.

My VS Code version is:

```
Version: 1.63.0
Commit: 7db1a2b88f7557e0a43fec75b6ba7e50b3e9f77e
Electron: 13.5.2
Chromium: 91.0.4472.164
Node.js: 14.16.0
V8: 9.1.269.39-electron.0
```

Answer (score 4):

VS Code doesn't have a key binding to toggle all breakpoints out of the box, in the current version (1.76.0).

Steps to assign a key binding manually:

1. Go to: File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts
2. Search for `toggleBreakpointsActivatedAction`
3. I set mines to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>, in line with other <kbd>F9</kbd> based key bindings related to "breakpoints"

[image]

Comment: It is not for all unfortunately. I want to toggle Caught and Uncaught Exceptions as well.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I have found it already - that can be achieved with `toggleBreakpointsActivatedAction`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).